# Linux Couldn't access full permission file

Tags: 18.04, permissions

I've a file in /var/ folder which is created by www-data application. Ownership and permission of the file is,

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   74214 Feb 18 17:00 sample.pdf
```

I tried to access this pdf by using non sudo user.

```
pdftk /var/myproj/www/sample.pdf
```

It gives me the error,

```
Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   /var/myproj/www/sample.pdf
```

For the sake, I've changed the permission to '`777`' and tried to access the same again.

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   74214 Feb 18 17:00 sample.pdf
```

This time also I'm getting the same error. I have changed that directory permission also to `777`. But It gives me the same error why? My ubuntu version is `'18.04'`.

Comment: `Unable to find file` makes me think the file just isn't located where you expect it to be. Please [edit] your post and add the output of `ls -ld /var /var/myproj /var/myproj/www /var/myproj/www/sample.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the permission on that specific file. And I do not recommend setting those permission on a folder, it is *very* insecure

So it would be

```
chmod 777 /var/myproj/www/sample.pdf
```

There is also a chance you don't own the file, so

```
chown your-user /var/myproj/www/sample.pdf
```

Please note that certain application will automatically rechange permissions back to default, and sudo is usually needed to change file permissions.